# CSS Float and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to control the sort order of divs on a page using a JSON object with a property of sort:

```
var json = {
modules: [{
    css: 'small',
    header: 'MES',
    sort: '2',
    elements: [{
        header: 'All'
    }, {
        header: "Retail"
    }, {
        header: 'Previous'
    }]
}, {
    css: 'small',
    header: 'QFS',
    sort: '1',
    elements: [{
        header: 'All'
    }, {
        header: "Retail"
    }, {
        header: 'Previous'
    }]
}, {
    css: 'small',
    header: 'QComm',
    sort: '3',
    elements: [{
        header: 'Current'
    }, {
        header: 'Previous'
    }]
}]
};
```

It's working fine and displaying nicely. However, if I change the sorts around from this, my third block gets displayed to the right underneath the second block, rather than underneath the first block on the left.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQRAT/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating is a bit tricky. If the 1) first box has let's say height: 200px and the 
2) second has 100px and the same for the 3) third 100px ..

you will see that on the left is just one box 1) ... on the right are both 2) and 3)

One way how to fix it is to assure, that all boxes are of the same height e.g. *`min-height: 150px;`*

```
.small {
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    min-height: 150px;  /* here we go */
}
```

But it could not be true once the content of one of the boxes will extend that height...

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that the boxes could be of different heights. I'll look into ways to get them to be the same height.